# strange output when typing a command on terminal

Tags: xfce4-terminal

when I type clear on my terminal, it outputs me with:

```
[3;J
```

and clears the screen.

Comment: It's probably a malformed [ANSI escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), however I couldn't guess where it's coming from. See also [How does clear command work](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124762/65304)

Comment: steeldriver left a comment on your question, not an answer, so you can't accept it as such! However you can upvote the comment, by clicking on the `^` symbol, that only becomes visible when hovering your cursor over his/her comment.

Comment: The command `stty sane` might remove the stray ANSI sequence.